# JSOM : run work flow using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, jsom

I am trying to run a workflow using JSOM for office365 workflow

I have used this cod to call the function :

```
<a href="javascript:startWorkflow(\'{FF71E26B-04B8-42CF-B641-30819F122C25}\', '19')">Request for update</a></li>
```

and for the java script :

```
function startWorkflow(itemID, subID) {

                        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                        var web = context.get_web();

                        var wfServiceManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);

                        var subscription = wfServiceManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().getSubscription(subID);

                        context.load(subscription);

                        context.executeQueryAsync(
                            function (sender, args) {
                                console.log("Subscription load success. Attempting to start workflow.");
                                //notify_i('Request failed', 'Subscription load success. Attempting to start workflow.' + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                                var inputParameters = {};

                                wfServiceManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(subscription, itemID, inputParameters);

                                context.executeQueryAsync(
                                    function (sender, args) { console.log("Successfully starting workflow."); },
                                    function (sender, args) {
                                        console.log("Failed to start workflow.");
                                        console.log("Error: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
                                    }
                                );
                            },
                            function (sender, args) {
                                console.log("Failed to load subscription.");
                                console.log("Error: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
                            }
                        );
                    }
```

I am getting this error message:

**Subscription load success. 
Attempting to start workflow.
OpenSubjects.aspx:806 
Failed to start workflow.
OpenSubjects.aspx:807 
Error: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: subscription
undefined**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to pass 3 parameters to you method, that only expects 2, and seem to have mixed up the order of them.

```
function startWorkflow(itemID, subID)
```

So you should first pass the `itemID`, the integet of the list item

And then the subscription id, the GUID of the workflow subscription.

Comment: yes , you are right the issues now changed :)